# does google crawler look keyword inside meta tag

Tags: search, search-engine

hi all i want to know that whether google look inside meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not use the **keywords** meta tag.  See [this posting on the Google blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).

It does use the **description** meta tag, to provide the page snippet in its results if it can't generate a useful snippet from the page content.

There are also some specific Google-supported meta tags [documented here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812).

Comment: can u suggest some best practice in for page ranking of page.

Comment: That's a huge topic, and very well covered on the web.  Search for beginners' SEO tutorials and you'll find a wealth of material.